# Intellij IDEA 10 + Python + Django does not run Apache Ant-scripts

Tags: python, django, ant, intellij-idea

Greetings! Intellij IDEA 10 + Python plugin when creating a project using Django, does not run Apache Ant-scripts. When I try to add an Ant-script error occurs «Cannot Add Files». I can’t understand reason of problem.

Comment: You may have to setup your ant/jdk configuration under the ant plugin tab.  I haven't looked at this in ages though...

Comment: Sorry, properties is unavailable. I don’t know how I can configure Ant with disabled buttons.

Comment: I just downloaded 10.0 build IU-99.18, installed it on OSX 10.6.  With a plain python project module (after installing plugin) the ant tab [+] allows me to add a file.  I can't run it until I add a Java JDK to the project and select it for running the ant file.  I don't have any django in the mix for testing.

Comment: With plain Python I have no problebs too. Issues occurs when I try to use Django in Python.

Comment: You are likely having problems with Run/Debug config for Django Server also.  I get the same problems you do.

Comment: When you try and create a new django project do you get an alert symbol when you select [django admin]? I had to recreate my py jdk to get it to properly pickup the django packages from site-packages.  I installed them using "sudo easy_install django", after which reconfiguring the python _jdk_ produced "/Library/Python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.2.3-py2.6.egg" in the _classpath_.  Mine now is setup to to work with ant.

Comment: No, I dont get any alerts when creating new django project. That what I have in classpath
>c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages
>c:\Python27\Lib
>c:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk
>c:\Python27
>c:\Python27\DLLs

Answer (score 0):

Which module type have you created? Please try to create a regular Java module with a Java SDK, and to add a Python facet to it.

Comment: I dont need Python facet. When I try to add Django facet error occurs «No suitable modules for Django facet found»